# Firebase invoke realtime database onCreate function locally

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

I have made a testing environment and try to invoke Firebase Realtime Database onCreate function locally with test data through Cloud Functions shell looking at the documents. But it gives an error. I may have misunderstood something.

> functions: TypeError: instance.INTERNAL.registerComponent is not a function at registerDatabase...

The code I try:

```
const testData = require('./test/testData.json')
requestSubmission(testData, {params:{accountKey: '-LwOLg3hWxXd8iNWBrUt', requestKey: '-M0Z5m8gGtfrgAER5KF'}})
```

My cloud function:

```
exports.requestSubmission = functions.database.ref('/requests/{accountKey}/{requestKey}')
   .onCreate((snap, context) => {
          //This is my original function.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for my problem while checking issues on github. I installed it in functions folder.

```
npm install @firebase/app --save
```